# How to add repeated data in Java array?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am having an array with name (`String name[]={"a","b","a","c","a","b","c"};`) and another array with quantity (`int qty[]={10,20,10,40,10,40,70};`) corresponding with name array. Now, i just want another array having addition of similar `qty[]` values corresponding to their `name[]` i.e. i need `tempname[]={"a","b","c"}` and `tempqty[]={30,60,110}`. here tempname contains unique values from name and tempqty contains addition of a,b,c.

```
temp=name;
    qty1=qty;
    for(i=0;i<name.length;i++){
        temp1=qty[i];
        for(int j=0;j<name.length;j++){
            if (name[i]==temp[j+1]){
                temp1=temp1+qty1[j+1];
            }
        }          
    }
```

I tried above method. Here, i am able to get addition of qty of "a" name but i am not getting my result. please suggest me on this or give me any another way to solve the problem. thank you in advance.

Comment: C does not have String type....

Comment: please add a MCVE _https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve_

Comment: @SouravGhosh It seems to be Java (see tags)

Comment: I would suggest you to use Maps

Comment: @CIsForCookies ok my bad

Comment: how to use Maps @LucaNicoletti please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily by ArrayList. I did this for you:

```
String name[]={"a","b","a","c","a","b","c"};
int qty[]={10,20,10,40,10,40,70};
ArrayList<String>tempname= new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Integer>tempqty= new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i=0;i<name.length;i++){
    int index=tempname.indexOf(name[i]);
    if(index==-1){
        tempname.add(name[i]);
        tempqty.add(qty[i]);
    }
    else{
        tempqty.set(index,tempqty.get(index)+qty[i]);
    }
}
for(int i=0;i<tempname.size();i++){
    System.out.printf(tempname.get(i)+" ");
}   
System.out.println();
for(int i=0;i<tempqty.size();i++){
    System.out.printf(tempqty.get(i)+" ");
}
```

Comment: So basically you convert from an array to an arraylist?

Comment: No. Where tempname list size is not predicted without calculation so I feel better to use arraylist for its dynamic array size. It can also solve my String array but there will some useless empty memory block.

Comment: Welcome @Tabishkhan :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a HashMap:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> quantity = new HashMap<>();
for(int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
    if(!quantity.containsKey(name[i])) {
        quantity.put(name[i], qty[i]);
    } else {
       quantity.put(name[i], quantity.get(name[i]) + qty[i]); 
    }
}
```

Untested, but you'll get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use something like hashmaps for this

Example:

```
HashMap<String, int> hmap = new HashMap<String, int>();
hmap.put("a", 1);
hmap.put("b", 2);
```

To get a value use

```
hmap.get("a"); // will give 1
```

To loop through everything

```
Iterator it= hmap.keySet().iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    String key=(String)it.next();
    int value=(int)hmap.get(key);
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put values together because they belong together you could create a class.

```
class MyStoreThing {
  String name;
  int quantity;
}

int getSummarizedQuantityOfAllWithName(String name) {
  int summarizedQuantity = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
    summarizedQuantity  += name.equals(myList.getName()) ? myList.getQuantity : 0;
  }
  return summarizedQuantity;
}

ArrayList<MyStoreThing> myList = new...;
// populate list: myList.add(new MyStoreThing("a", 10)) ...
// call getSummarizedQuantityOfAllWithName("a");
```